# Android UI design suggestion on ViewFlipper

Tags: performance, android

Typical Sliding menu and content app. So i have designed it content as ViewFlipper and when menu item (Navigation drawer) is selected based on item i do a setDisplayedChild(position). So its pretty good in condition with animations and colors.

The app is in final stage and review says they need me put few background and some Image buttons, the problem i am facing is since in ViewFlipper all the children are prepared and loaded to memory at initial stage itself memory consumption has gone high (30Mb more).

Only option i have is to change ViewFlipper so that one required child view is in memory. What alternative should i follow to minimize the my rework and testing.

My Activity is Fragment Activity and each child is in different layout.

Comment: Have a look at ViewPager and PagerAdapter, especially FragmentPagerAdapter and if you say your memory consumption is high, you want to have a special look at FragmentStatePagerAdapter. With a ViewPager you can set an offscreen page limit...

Comment: FragmentStatePagerAdapter is new to me and worth to consider for my case, thank you. Using View Pager needs my child to be a Fragment Activity which would be 1 day dev and 1 day testing work. i would like to consider other options before going with FragmentStatePagerAdapter.